# How to let Django use mysqlclient instead of mysqlDB

Tags: python, mysql, django, pythonanywhere

I'm on PythonAnywhere, python 3.4, Django latest version, virtualenv, using mac os x. I tried to install both mysqlclient and mysqlDB on my virtualenv on PythonAnywhere, mysqlDB failed because it is not compatible with python3, mysqlclient successfully installed but Django seems to be unable to detect mysqlclient and use it instead of mysqldb. Here is the error log:

```
2015-05-22 12:13:36,953 :Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-05-22 12:13:36,953 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 14, in <module>
2015-05-22 12:13:36,954 :    import MySQLdb as Database
2015-05-22 12:13:36,954 :ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
2015-05-22 12:13:36,955 :
2015-05-22 12:13:36,955 :During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2015-05-22 12:13:36,955 :
2015-05-22 12:13:36,955 :Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-05-22 12:13:36,955 :  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 130, in __call__
2015-05-22 12:13:36,955 :    self.error_log_file.logger.exception("Error running WSGI application")
2015-05-22 12:13:36,955 :  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 1296, in exception
2015-05-22 12:13:36,956 :    self.error(msg, *args, **kwargs)
2015-05-22 12:13:36,956 :  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 1289, in error
2015-05-22 12:13:36,957 :    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
2015-05-22 12:13:36,957 :  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 1395, in _log
2015-05-22 12:13:36,958 :    self.handle(record)
2015-05-22 12:13:36,958 :  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 1404, in handle
2015-05-22 12:13:36,959 :    if (not self.disabled) and self.filter(record):
2015-05-22 12:13:36,959 :  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 692, in filter
2015-05-22 12:13:36,960 :    for f in self.filters:
2015-05-22 12:13:36,960 :  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 122, in __call__
2015-05-22 12:13:36,960 :    app_iterator = self.app(environ, start_response)
2015-05-22 12:13:36,960 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
2015-05-22 12:13:36,961 :    self.load_middleware()
2015-05-22 12:13:36,961 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware
2015-05-22 12:13:36,962 :    mw_class = import_by_path(middleware_path)
2015-05-22 12:13:36,962 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 21, in import_by_path
2015-05-22 12:13:36,963 :    module = import_module(module_path)
2015-05-22 12:13:36,963 :  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
2015-05-22 12:13:36,964 :    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2015-05-22 12:13:36,964 :  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
2015-05-22 12:13:36,966 :  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
2015-05-22 12:13:36,966 :  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2015-05-22 12:13:36,966 :  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
2015-05-22 12:13:36,966 :  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
2015-05-22 12:13:36,967 :  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1448, in exec_module
2015-05-22 12:13:36,967 :  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
2015-05-22 12:13:36,967 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 3, in <module>
2015-05-22 12:13:36,972 :    from django.contrib.auth.backends import RemoteUserBackend
2015-05-22 12:13:36,973 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py", line 3, in <module>
2015-05-22 12:13:36,974 :    from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
2015-05-22 12:13:36,974 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 48, in <module>
2015-05-22 12:13:36,975 :    class Permission(models.Model):
2015-05-22 12:13:36,975 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 96, in __new__
2015-05-22 12:13:36,976 :    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
2015-05-22 12:13:36,976 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 264, in add_to_class
2015-05-22 12:13:36,977 :    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
2015-05-22 12:13:36,977 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 124, in contribute_to_class
2015-05-22 12:13:36,978 :    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
2015-05-22 12:13:36,978 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
2015-05-22 12:13:36,978 :    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
2015-05-22 12:13:36,978 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 198, in __getitem__
2015-05-22 12:13:36,979 :    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
2015-05-22 12:13:36,979 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
2015-05-22 12:13:36,980 :    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
2015-05-22 12:13:36,980 :  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
2015-05-22 12:13:36,980 :    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2015-05-22 12:13:36,980 :  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
2015-05-22 12:13:36,980 :    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
2015-05-22 12:13:36,980 :django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

my settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'chart',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

I have traversed through some posts on stackoverflow but no one seems to address my problem. Let me know if you have any good suggestions, thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you installed `mysqlclient`? Can you `import MySQLdb` in a Python shell? Does it appear in `pip freeze`?

Answer (score 1):

Truth discovered: It's actually PythonAnywhere's configuration problem, they have their own MySQL configurations you have to follow and you can't use mysqlclient because they only use Oracle mysql connector.

Thanks everyone for reading and answering.

Answer (score 1):

The stacktrace indicates that you're not running your web app from a virtualenv. You need to correctly configure your web app to use a particular virtualenv.

Also, the connection properties in your settings.py will not work. The correct connection details are on the Databases tab for your account.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "detecting mysqlclient". Mysqlclient is a fork of MySQLdb, and from a Python perspective they're the same module, but simply different versions.

You probably have conflicting files from both installations. I would completely remove both MySQLdb and mysqlclient, and then reinstall mysqlclient only. That should fix your problems.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I discovered that it's PythonAnywhere's configuration problem, they have their own MySQL configurations you have to follow and you can't use mysqlclient because they only use Oracle mysql connector. Thank you very much though.